# Am Using Yii,And I want to Style a DIV Element by defining the CSS properies on the View and then later save the CSS file

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, yii

I want users to have the ability to style A Parent div properties. By defining the div color, back-ground and other css properties from the interface more of the wordpress theming dashboad. Someone point me int right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to facilitate user to be able to select custom settings for the css options then you can do this by using cookies. You can try these steps
1. Change the extension of your css file to .php and add these lines to start of this file

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css;");

?>
```

Also change extension of this file to .php where you are using this.

2. create a table with the same attributes which u want to save the setting like color, width,height. 

3. Then in you main.php file query that table to get the properties then set the cookies as

```
Yii::app()->request->cookies['bg1'] = new CHttpCookie('nameOfattribute','value from database');
```

4. Now in you .php style file(previously Css file) set the attributes of the classes to the values you get from cookie like

```
banner {
    background-color:<?php echo $_COOKIE['bg1r']; ?>;
    width: 100%;
    height: 436px;
}
```

and include the same class where you want it to be.

 You can render a form and take input from user against these attributes and save them in database Table.

Comment: WOW! this make a lot more sense. I didn't know that declaring 'code' <?php header("content-type : text/css;"); ?> 'code' and changing the file to .php would allow me to use variables and arrays in the css. I think my nightmare is over.

Comment: remember the CSS classes should be written in the same way as they are written in .css file. Only just header is included

Comment: try above code and if it works for you then mark the answer as accepted Because new yii user normally search this topic on google by writing yii but this topic is partially yii related thats y user cant find any related solution. So it may helo those users. If it do not work then do let me know

Comment: @Razfay Zia Mir am thinking of having the css properties from the database by having them on a session and later call it on my cssfile.php the problem is that the    Yii::app()->session['tag']['width'] cant be initialize in the cssfile.php. Any advise

Comment: Did you try Yii::app()->user->setState("state_name","value");?
Yii::app()->user->getState("state_name");?